# max integer and min integer in standard ml

Tags: types, max, min, sml

I want to use the max integer and min integer from ml, but I cant, I saw from the library its of type int option, how can I use it? I saw it in here [http://www.standardml.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG:INTEGER.minInt:VAL](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG%3aINTEGER.minInt%3aVAL)

I want to use it to make a max and min function, each method take a list of integers and I have to return the max and min respectively.

I've tried the following codes but they didnt work:

```
- fun max x = 
=   foldr (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else b) INTEGER.minInt x;

- fun max x = 
=   foldr (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else b) minInt x;

- fun max x = 
=   foldr (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else b) Int.minInt x;
```

Does anybody know how to use them?

Answer (score 5):

`Int.minInt` and `Int.maxInt` are of the type `int option` and not `int`.

This means, they can either be on the form `NONE`, if there is no maximum (or minimum), or on the form `SOME v`, where `v` is the maximum (or minimum).

There are many ways of obtaining the value from an option.

- Pattern matching.
- [`valOf`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/option.html#SIG%3aOPTION.valOf%3aVAL), which extracts the value. (note, raises an exception if given `NONE`)
- [`getOpt`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/option.html#SIG%3aOPTION.getOpt%3aVAL), which extracts the value, and uses a default value if it's given `NONE`.

For this particular problem, however, you can do it without needing `Int.minInt`, if you do some pattern matching on the input. Also, remember to consider the case where your input list is empty.

Comment: I tried using pattern matching, by making the list as x::xs, but it gives me a warning of match non-exhaustive, what could it be due to?

Comment: the new fun that worked is : fun max (x::xs) = foldr (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else b) x (x::xs);

Comment: Remember to consider the empty list.